# Send parameter from subchild component to parent component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have this structure of components

Parent Component --> Child Component --> SubChild Component

So, in the sub-child component I have an `$emit` event as:

```
   <HTMLTag
            @input="$emit('update:table-range', $event)"
          />
```

So I can receive it on the child component as:

```
 <SubChildComponent
      @update:table-range="onUpdateFilter"
    />
```

But I do not want to use on child component, I want to use on the parent, how can I send it thought the child to the parent?

ParentComponent:

```
  <ChildComponent @update:table-range="onUpdateFilter" />
```

This does not work

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emit it again from the Child component

```js
<SubChildComponent
      @update:table-range="$emit('update:table-range', $event)"
/>
```

By the way, when you start passing data between multiple levels of components, you may want to instead consider a state management library such as [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) which provides a single central location for data that all components can easily access.

Comment: can you provide an example of how to achieve this using Vuex?

Comment: well there's quite a bit of code needed to initially set up vuex, you would just follow the docs for that. once set up though it's pretty easy.  say for example if you had some count variable you want to use everywhere you'd add it to your store's state, then one component can set it's value like `this.$store.state.count = 5` and any other component can access it with the same `this.$store.state.count`.  the point of vuex is that you don't have to emit or listen to `count` changing between components, `count` lives in the store which all components have instant access to